# User-friendly display of a Unix epoch field in a Ruby on Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model (representing an event) with three fields: a start date as integer, being thought as an Unix epoch, a corresponding end date and another integer being an interval in seconds - this interval being the period (ie. start+interval it happens, start+2*interval it happens again) of the event.

I would like to make a controller and a view for editing this. Currently, I have 3 text fields. But I would like to make this more user friendly. Maybe displaying a calendar or something like that. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you asking about the conversions? `Time.parse(string).to_i` returns epoch and `Time.at(integer)` returns a `Time` object that you can use with calendar forms.

Comment: You can use [Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) for start and end date. To set format in UNIX timestamp (miliseconds) use `$('#startTime').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", '@');`